# nullptr vs __nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-cli

I was just wondering why there are two ways to specify null pointer. I have been going through the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215%28VS.100%29.aspx), but did not get clear understanding of its use.

Can someone give a good example of when to use what?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The C++/CLI language already had a `nullptr` keyword since 2005.  That caused a problem when C++11 adopted the nullptr keyword for C++.  Now there are two, one for managed code and another for native code.  The C++/CLI compiler can compile both.  So you have to use __nullptr when you mean the native null pointer, nullptr when you mean the managed null pointer.

This is only relevant when you compile with /clr in effect.  Write C++/CLI code in other words.  Just use plain nullptr in C++ code.

Comment: I think that the bit about /clr is probably the most important part of this answer.  If you are not concerned with hooking your C++ code up to the .NET Framework, then you should always use `nullptr`.

Comment: Being really pedantic, it was already a (though rarely relevant before) problem with porting C++ code to C++/CLI before C++11 existed.

Comment: I have the same issue in a C++/CLI application. Hans explanation makes it clear where it comes from. But, in my case the code uses try/catch blocks. However, the error is not flagged in my code but in a microsoft include "exception" (no extension), in six places like this:

Comment: exception_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept {
        __ExceptionPtrCreate(this);
    } the file is from the VC toolset.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case when Micosoft wrote a good explanation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/nullptr-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) - it is identical to the actepted answer in this thread: "in native code use nullptr, in C++/CLI use nullptr for managed objects and __nullptr for native pointer".

However, it the very same article Microsoft shown examples, which completely ignore this advice:

```
// mcpp_nullptr.cpp
// compile with: /clr
value class V {};
ref class G {};
void f(System::Object ^) {}

int main() {
// Native pointer.
   int *pN = nullptr;
// Managed handle.
   G ^pG = nullptr;
```

So in fact you can use nullptr for both managed and native pointers. Compiler doesn't generate error or warning in this case. Also code works like expected. And only if you want to explicitly say in your code "hey, this is a NATIVE pointer, look, this is important!" - you can use __nullptr. So this is more about showing the meaning of nullptr to another programmer, not about the code corectness for compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you should use `nullptr` for managed pointers, and `__nullptr` for unmanaged pointer. However, since `nullptr` can be used for both managed an unmanaged pointer, I personally don't see a reason to use `__nullptr`.

Comment: But, if you are compiling with the /clr switch, how can the compiler know if you are using the C++11 `nullptr` or the C++/CLI `nullptr`?  It cannot, which is the reason why you *must* use `__nullptr` when you mean the C++11 version when you are compiling with the /clr switch.

Comment: The reason to use __nullptr is because if you use nullptr then you will **never** be able to turn on C++/CLI and make use of .NET. Which is a big disadvantage in terms of using legacy code in the future.